# Nss version Update (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, mozilla, nss

On my ubuntu PC I have nss version 3.28.4 and I wanna update the version to 3.30.2 how can I do that easly. I found [this way](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/security/nss/releases/NSS_3_30_2_RTM/src/) but I need easiest way for my client. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

If it is Ubuntu also, why not try `sudo apt-get install libnss3*`? This will install/update all packages starting with `libnss3`. As I know it is the easiest way. To be verbose, add `-v`.

If you want to be sure about the packages starting with `libnss3` are really what you want, use `dpkg -l libnss3*` to list all the package starting with `libnss3`, and use `apt show package-name` to check description of each.